# I can't purge kubuntu-desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, kubuntu

I had Kubuntu for about a week now and I don't like it, so I want to switch to Ubuntu. I opened the terminal and ran `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and it installed everything. Later when the installation was finished I ran `sudo apt-get --purge remove kubuntu-desktop` and it gave me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'kubuntu-desktop' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-scope-gdrive : Depends: account-plugin-google but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. 
 Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

But when I even went to Synaptic, it said I still have that package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Synaptic and click on the blue Reload button in the upper left corner to reload the list of installed packages.
2. Check in Synaptic if kubuntu-desktop is still installed.
3. Close Synaptic (or else you will get an error in Step 5).
4. Open the terminal.
5. Run the following commands to resolve the unmet dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt update  
   sudo apt upgrade  
   sudo apt install account-plugin-google   
   sudo apt -f install
   ```
6. If you get an unmet dependencies error, run only the last two commands:

   ```
   sudo apt install account-plugin-google   
   sudo apt -f install
   ```

Comment: Alright so I can't access Kubuntu or Ubuntu anymore, the Kubuntu loading splash pops up but then a Ubuntu styled prompt pops up and says something about configuring driver errors I think, and then I click OK and it gives more 4 options, one of them had to do with drivers, the other one said something about console login I think, and the next one let me review these text files that showed my the logs of it booting up and stuff, and the last one I forgot. Can you help me? I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: If the error message identifies a specific driver, then you can select the console option, login to the console, uninstall that driver from the console, run the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common` and reboot using the command `sudo reboot`. This will force Ubuntu to use the default open source driver instead, and then Ubuntu may be able to boot.

Comment: But when I click the login to console option, it just gives me a black screen.

Comment: It is also possible to login to the console using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+F1. Please read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/438783/how-to-switch-to-a-command-line-console/438804#438804) for a complete, step-by-step explanation of how to login to the console starting from Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command , it will give you all details of package names

```
dpkg -l | grep kubuntu.*
```

Now manually remove every packages

```
dpkg -r "package name"
```

After removing related packages , You will be able to install any thing.

Comment: This asterisk (`*`) in the first command is weird. It triggers shell globbing, so if one has a file like `kubuntu-foo` in their current directory, the latter part of the command becomes `grep kubuntu-foo`. I guess you don't want this. To avoid it, quote the pattern: `"kubuntu*"`; but this will match `kubunt`, `kubuntu`, `kubuntuu`, etc. Did you mean `"kubuntu.*"`? Then why not just `kubuntu`? Please review your answer and improve it maybe.

Comment: Yes!, there should be kubuntu.* This command will give you all those packages name which has been installed and related to kubunut. once you will identify that package which has not been purged, you need to manually purge it and then you will be able to install new one

Comment: The command is still prone to shell globbing.